# How should I get know that all values in HashMap is visited once?

Tags: java, string, hashmap, substring

Here, I'm trying to find shortestSubstring from a string and i'm not able to find a way of how should i get to know if all the values of hashmap is visited once or not in O(1), or is there any another way to do it?

```
String mainString = "abacbbdabc";
String targetString = "adc";
```

HashMap will iterate and updating values until it find out all the characters from the `targetString` i.e first substring will be from index `0 to 6`

```
public String findShortestSubstring(String mainString, String targetString) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < targetString.length(); i++) {
            map.put(targetString.charAt(i), 1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mainString.length(); i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(mainString.charAt(i))) {
                map.put(mainString.charAt(i), 0);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Having difficulty following exactly what you're trying to do - but if it is "how do I establish that all the characters in mainString are in targetString) then why not map.remove(mainString.charAt(i)) in your second loop and then check map.isEmpty()? If it is, "mainString" will contain at least all the characters in "targetString"

Comment: @NotaJD :  We can't remove characters from the targetString, as we have to iterate through the whole mainString until we found the shortest substring.

Comment: I didn't suggest remove characters from the targetString...

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand properly:

I would use ArrayList. Try to split on single letter every element into list. For example

```
mainString=skldfjkldfgj; // split it ["s","k","l","d","f","j","k","l","d","f","g","j"]
targetString=dfj;  //split it too ["d","f","j"]
```

You know dfj is split into 3 elements into ArrayList. If you find first letter of targetString in mainString then check next 2 elements if they matches.

Comment: Order of targetStirng does not matter here, we only have to check is all character from a targetString is visited once or not..

Comment: So you can increment variable when you find the letter and rember substring. Is this answer enough?

Comment: String mainString = "abacbbdabc";
String targetString = "adc";

Index : 0 to 6 where I found all all the character
map  : a:1,  d:1, c:1

Then, i will be increment from 0th index until will get rid of one of the element from mainString
abacbbd
bacbbd
acbbd

When it comes to
cbbd
We have to increment, from tail index
cbbda
and so on..